# TCP server handling multiple connections

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am trying to write a TCP server which handles multiple connections.

I know the way Java does it with sockets is that it has a pool of threads, the server has a while loop waiting for connections and when 'accpets' one it 'gets' a thread from the pool to handle the request.
I was picturing something similar with actors.

```
class TcpServer(remote: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor {

  import Tcp._
  import context.system

  IO(Tcp) ! Bind(self, remote)

  def receive = {
    case b @ Bound(localAddress) =>
      context.parent ! b

    case CommandFailed(_: Bind) ⇒ context stop self

    case c @ Connected(remote, local) =>
      val handler: ActorRef =  context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[SimplisticHandler]), "router")
      sender() ! Register(handler)
  }
```

But obviously, that is not enough. What am i missing here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you expanded on "obviously that is not enough".  What is wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "not enough".  The idiom I've seen and used for TCP-listening actors is that you have an actor for each connection (since the actors are scheduled on a thread pool by the dispatcher, actor-per-connection is equivalent to getting a thread from the pool to handle the request), without pooling the actors

Comment: I also note that `context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(...))` will create a new pool with every connection and throw that pool away after the connection closes, so if you're intent on reusing actors (which is at the very least not idiomatic), you should create the pool outside of the `receive`.

Comment: In fact, thinking about it further, unless the connection is intended to be fully stateless, since it's very likely that successive chunks of bytes received from the client will be routed to a different `SimplisticHandler`, using the `RoundRobinPool` isn't a good idea.

Comment: by "not enough" i meant that when i try a second connection, it gets this ` was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.` and the handlers do not receive any messages. So , i guess, that's not the right wat to do it.

@LeviRamsey What is the idiomatic way

Comment: `val handler = context.actorOf(Props[SimplisticHandler])`.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to post code for `SimplisticHandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Akka TCP the pattern generally used is to have one actor handle the connection.  Since actors get scheduled onto threads as needed by the `ActorSystem`'s dispatcher, the pattern of getting a thread from a thread pool is provided more or less automatically by Akka (it's possible to, for instance, configure the default dispatcher to be a pool of a single thread, but that's not default and not recommended).

With that in mind, you'll want to replace the

```
context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(5).props(Props[SimplisticHandler]), "router")
```

with

```
context.actorOf(Props[SimplisticHandler])
```

and be sure in `SimplisticHandler` to

```
context.stop.self
```

in response to a `ConnectionClosed` message.